# Not able to install latest mercurial release on fedora

Tags: mercurial, fedora

I am trying to install latest mercurial on fedora by doing sudo yum install mercurial .

But doing so I am getting mercurial 1.1 that is not latest release .Current mercurial release is 1.6+ .

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: This is more appropriate for superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's entirely a fedora thing.  The primary act of a linux distribution is the selecting and bundling of software, and they pick the versions to make available.  Some of them try to stay very in sync with the software they include and some update less frequently.  Fedora's offical distributions have 1.1 as their latest revision.

Your options are to either add a different repository source that's not directly managed by fedora, install the software not from package, or to switch distributions to one that ships a more current mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Fedora do you have? The version of Mercurial bundled with Fedora is currently 1.6.4. If you update your Fedora version, you should then get an updated Mercurial.

```
[root@rollins ~]# cat /etc/system-release
Fedora release 13 (Goddard)
```

In my Fedora 13 system, I get the following:

```
[root@rollins ~]# yum info mercurial
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Found 36 installed debuginfo package(s)
Enabling fedora-debuginfo: Fedora 13 - i386 - Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-nonfree-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 13 - Nonfree - Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 13 - Free - Updates Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 13 - Nonfree - Updates Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-free-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 13 - Free - Debug
Enabling updates-debuginfo: Fedora 13 - i386 - Updates - Debug
Installed Packages
Name        : mercurial
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.6.4
Release     : 3.fc13
Size        : 6.4 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Mercurial -- a distributed SCM
URL         : http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : Mercurial is a fast, lightweight source control management system designed
            : for efficient handling of very large distributed projects.
            : 
            : Quick start: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/QuickStart
            : Tutorial: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/Tutorial
            : Extensions: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/CategoryExtension
```